# Error while using HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets

I want to retrieve in the request data in my services which is being called using restangular in web. So I have autowired HttpServletRequest, but when i am trying to get the data, I am getting the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"FATAL_ERROR","type":"ERROR","message":"Current request is not a servlet request"}],"status":"ERROR","errorCode":500,"errorStatus":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}
```

My code goes as follows:

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
@Path("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
    @POST
    @Path("/userDetails")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response
    getUserDetails() {
    System.out.printl(httpServletRequest;);
```

Comment: What are you expecting from httpservlet request in doing a rest call?

Comment: What is the scope of Your UserController bean?